# Django custom tags validation

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, django-apps, django-custom-tags

I'm getting this error -> Invalid filter: 'cutter'
while this is my custom tags.py:

```
from django import template
from random import randint

register = template.Library()


def cutter(list, args):
    return list[args]

register.filter('cutter', cutter)
```

a short part of index.html:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}main{% endblock title %}
{% block home %}active{% endblock home %}
{% block body %}

<span>{{regions_count|cutter:forloop.counter0}}</span>

{% endblock body %}
```

and my directory is this:

```
my_app/
├── ...
├── templatetags/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── _pycache_(folder)
|   └── custom_tags.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: is the `custom_tags.py` located in the folder `templatetags`?

Comment: yes this is my directory:

project - base(app) - templatetags - _pycache_(folder) & _init_.py & custom_tags.py

Comment: ok where is your index.html template located? in the same `my_app` ?

Comment: Did you make sure your app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: i tried to write the directory in a short way. index.html is also in  templates folder and it works. I'm Also sure that my app is in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with following:

custom_tags.py (list is a bad name for a variable - because it shadows built in list function)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def cutter(entry_list, args):
    return entry_list[args]

register.filter('cutter', cutter)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% load custom_tags %}
{% block title %}main{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <span>{{ regions | cutter:0 }}</span>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Region

def index(request):
    context = {
        'regions': Region.objects.all()
    }
    return HttpResponse(render(request, 'index.html', context))
```

and this directory structure:

```
my_project
├── my_app/
|  ├── ...
|  ├── templates
|  |   └── index.html
|  ├── templatetags/
|  |   └── custom_tags.py
|  └── views.py
```

Everything works fine and I get the first Region object printed.